# TinyMCE 4.9.6 TinyMce.min.js File Getting Error Message

Tags: tinymce-4

In "TinyMCE 4.9.6" version while Run in asp.net Error Occurring "JavaScript runtime error: Object expected" In Below Specific tinymce.min.js file the Error Occured [TinyMCE 4 Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3xDm.png) 
Can you Please Give Solution For this.

TinyMce.min.js  Error Occuring Locrion.
M=function(e,t,n,r){if(Jt.isArray(e)){for(var o=e.length;o--;)e[o]=M(e[o],t,n,r);return e}return!u.collect||e!==a&&e!==i||l.push([e,t,n,r]),m.bind(e,t,n,r||V)}

Comment: Please review how to create a Minimal, Reproducable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  The data you have provided really won't allow anyone to help you.

Comment: kindly view the Screen shoot "TinyMCE 4 Error Image" try to give any solution or alternative solution